# Java, SQL Database Connection eror

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am newbie, is learning to make the program connect to the mysql database, but there is an error. i want to know how to look for url jdbc: mysql:

```
public class KoneksiDatabase {
private static Connection koneksi;
public static Connection getKoneksi(){
    if (koneksi == null) {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/universitas";
            String user = "root";
            String pasword = "kendo";

            DriverManager.registerDriver (new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            koneksi = DriverManager.getConnection (url, user, pasword);
        } catch (SQLException t) {
            System.out.println ("Eror Java Database Connection");
        }

    }
    return koneksi;
}
```

Comment: What error? What error message? This information is kind of somewhat sort of important.

Comment: Mysql generally run on port 3306, did you forgot to mention port number in url?

Comment: example when run, Eror Java Database Connection
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at program.universitas.Form.loadData(Form.java:39)
 at program.universitas.Form.<init>(Form.java:31)

Comment: OK, so what are lines 39 and 31 in the Form class? Please ask a more complete question, one that doesn't require that we continue to extract information out of you. Please go through the [help] and the [ask].

Comment: Did `Eror Java Database Connection` print? If so, log the actual exception using `t.printStackTrace();`

Comment: These are lines in the Form class, a class you're not posting.

Comment: @crack_iT port number already tried but still wrong, I am still confused how to input url.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the mysql-connector.jar file into your Library? It's an external resource not included with the default java package.

Comment: mysql-connector.jar file has been added to the library, but when in run error occurs.  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException